# Confusion with the case of “In den Wald joggen”

Tags: dative, accusative

A text in my German book contains the sentence:

> Oder wir gehen zuerst in die Stadt und danach **in den Wald joggen**.

I think that *in den Wald* actually has to be *in **dem** Wald* because here we ask the question “Where are they jogging?” and not “To where are there jogging?”, i.e., “Wo?” and not “Wohin?” which means we have to use dative and not accusative. Unless, of course, what they mean is that they want to go jogging to the forest, go inside and then go back, which I doubt they mean.

Can anyone explain this, please?

Comment: I would suggest a comma between *Wald* and *joggen*, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: @Jan: Optional (§ 75 E2).

Comment: @chirlu optional, but helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You obviously already know about dative and accusative when used with locations, the former generally meaning *something being there* and the latter *something going there*.

Here, the sentence does not necessarily say that you are going to jog into the forest. Rather, after having gone *to town*, you’re going to go *to the forest* and then do some jogging there. The active verb that governs the case of *in den Wald* is *gehen* in the sense of *going somewhere* (not walking). You should ask for this by asking: ‘To where are they going to go jogging?’

As User Unknown correctly points out, you don’t have to do all your jogging in the forest, you’re just starting there.

An optional (as per Chirlu’s comment, according to § 75 E2) comma could be inserted to clarify this reading:

> Danach gehen wir in den Wald, joggen.

---

You *could* also stress the fact that you are jogging in the forest more by saying:

> Danach gehen wir im Wald joggen.

Asking for this would result in the question you suggested: ‘Where are they jogging?’ But that’s a slightly different sentence.